# Can I use lock to ensure instruction order?

Tags: go, concurrency, mutex, memory-model

As stated in this link https://golang.org/ref/mem, the code below uses an incorrect synchronization:

```golang
var a, b int

func f() {
    a = 1
    b = 2
}

func g() {
    print(b)
    print(a)
}

func main() {
    go f()
    g()
}
```

Because it's possible that it prints a = 0 and b = 2.

However, I wonder if this result is possible in the code below where a and b are protected with Lock:

```golang
var a, b int
var mu sync.Mutex

func f() {
    mu.Lock()
    a = 1
    b = 2
    mu.Unlock()
}

func g() {
    mu.Lock()
    print(b)
    print(a)
    mu.Unlock()
}

func main() {
    go f()
    g()
}
```

Because the link says:

`For any sync.Mutex or sync.RWMutex variable l and n < m, call n of l.Unlock() happens before call m of l.Lock() returns.`

However, it is not clear about whether the assignment of a and b is guaranteed to be executed before the `Unlock` statement

Comment: The first lock is unblocking operation, a system call is. You are locking on the print operation. When the thread entering system call (awaiting operation), it creates conditions to switch context to the created before goroutine. It meets the second lock and waits until the first lock will be unlocked. As a result, variables will be changed only after printing.

Comment: @LaevusDexter: that is incorrect, there is no implied synchronization just because `g` invokes a syscall. There is no guarantee that the scheduler will return to `main` before `f` takes the lock and changes the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is guaranteed that once `f` executes `mu.Unlock()`, all goroutines reading `a` and `b` will see the updated values of `a` and `b` provided those goroutines also access `a` and `b` using the same lock. If there are goroutines that read `a` and `b` without lock then there is a race.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. Does this imply that any statement before an Unlock statement in the code is guaranteed to be executed before the Unlock statement?

Comment: Yes, that is guaranteed. For a single goroutine, it is always guaranteed to be that way. For multiple goroutines, locking guarantees that the execution of those instructions are visible to other goroutines.

Answer (score 4):

The code is safe in regard that it has no data race.

The behavior is not defined though. There is no synchronization regarding goroutine scheduling, so it may be that `g()` locks the mutex first, and once it releases, `main()` ends and your app may end with it, and `f()` might not complete (might not even start). The app may print nothing, may print `2`, or may print `21`.

It may also be that `f()` locks first, carriers out the assignments, and then `g()` in `main()` will print the assigned new values: `21`.

If you want `f()` to assign first, you may use a `sync.WaitGroup`, e.g.:

```
var a, b int
var wg sync.WaitGroup

func f() {
    defer wg.Done()
    a = 1
    b = 2
}

func g() {
    print(b)
    print(a)
}

func main() {
    wg.Add(1)
    go f()
    wg.Wait()
    g()
}
```

This will always print `21`, try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/vxAQrKh1WBD).

And a convoluted example to prove it can be solved with `sync.Mutex` too. This is not its designed use, but this also works:

Lock `mu` in the `main()`, before launching the goroutine. Have `g()` also lock, which will obviously block at first. `f()` can unlock it once its job is done, giving "green light" to `g()`:

```
var a, b int
var mu sync.Mutex

func f() {
    a = 1
    b = 2
    mu.Unlock()
}

func g() {
    mu.Lock()
    print(b)
    print(a)
    mu.Unlock()
}

func main() {
    mu.Lock()
    go f()
    g()
}
```

Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/4rPbJNnqVNK).